# "ERROR: Failed building wheel for chroma-hnswlib" trying to install chromadb on Mac / VScode

Tags: python, macos, chromadb

I tried to install chromadb on my .venv and I got the ERROR: Failed building wheel for chroma-hnswlib.

More info about the error below:

```
[Building wheel for chroma-hnswlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Building wheel for chroma-hnswlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
exit code: 1
[17 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel

*Continues the error (...)*

clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-march=native'
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for chroma-hnswlib
Failed to build chroma-hnswlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for chroma-hnswlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects]
```

I'm using VS code in a Mac. Python version 3.11.4 in my .venv

Already tried updating Pip and the Setup tools, didn't worked. Anyone has another solution for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip install on Mac OS gets error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64881510/pip-install-on-mac-os-gets-error-command-usr-bin-clang-failed-with-exit-code)

Comment: Like I said on the main post, I tried updating pip and setuptools, but the erros is still happening... Thanks for trying to help anyways.

Comment: There are plenty of other answers on that same post; have you tried any of those other 9?

Comment: Yes, all the ones that I could relate to my error and that I could understand, none worked until now. I'll try to use another version of Python trough pyenv next, that's the one missing from there, but I just started coding so I need to understand how to do that more specifically before doing it.

Comment: @esqew using python 3.8.13 with pyenv worked well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Following up on @Harit Sharma's answer:
it requires Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater
Therefore install Microsoft C++ Build Tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
Then follow the steps on: https://github.com/bycloudai/InstallVSBuildToolsWindows

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install build tools to build. Can get from here:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/