# How to pip install chromadb? FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file cannot be found

Tags: python, pip, chromadb

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 系统找不到指定的文件。（it's meanning : the system cannot find the file specilied）
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iw8E.png)

i update my pip but still faild .

my command is "pip install chromadb"

my python version is 3.12.1

my pip version is  23.3.2

my computer system is Windows10

output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t38fu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpiSH.png)

Comment: Can you post the full error?

Comment: can't understand this 系统找不到指定的文件。Kindly post full error message in English.

Comment: what command did you run to install this package?

Comment: I used command is     pip install chromadb

Comment: Please post the command you have entered, plus the complete output of the command.  I am sure the output listed the name of the file that was not found.  Otherwise, we can only help you with pure luck.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76856170/error-failed-building-wheel-for-chroma-hnswlib-trying-to-install-chromadb-on or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64881510/pip-install-on-mac-os-gets-error-command-usr-bin-clang-failed-with-exit-code These may be related questions.

Comment: I post my command and output now.

Comment: My suggestion, try to downgrade your python version to 3.11 and then use a virtual environment to see if it helps.