# Error: command '/usr/bin/clang/' failed with exit code 1, Could not build wheels for aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api

I'm trying to install openai using pip3 intall openai. I have Python 3.12 installed. I keep getting this error:

aiohttp/_websocket.c:3744:47: error: no member named 'ob_digit' in 'struct _longobject'
const digit* digits = ((PyLongObject*)b)->ob_digit;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
6 warnings and 5 errors generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I also get the same error when trying to install pyautogen.

I've also tried to solutions listed in this post: [Pip install on Mac OS gets error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64881510/pip-install-on-mac-os-gets-error-command-usr-bin-clang-failed-with-exit-code)

None seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same error in the same context, although it is important to note the actual error pertains to the aiohttp package, not openai itself.  Here's a workaround.

It seems aiohttp doesn't play nicely with Python 3.12: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/7229 (you'll see the form of the error is the same complaint about PyLongObject lacking a member called ob_digit).

Because I was pressed for time and wasn't going to fuss over the error itself, and I happened to have Pyenv installed with Python 3.9.18 already on my system, I could simply switch to that version by doing:

```
$ pyenv global 3.9.18
```

And then confirming it had "taken" by doing:

```
$ python -V
```

Thereafter, a simple

```
$ pip install openai
```

Rattled through the installation process.

If you don't have pyenv, you can get it here along with installation instructions for your system (probably): https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

And then you can install 3.9.18 (example, since it's known to be working, at least for me, but I'm sure other versions will too) by doing:

```
$ pyenv install 3.9.18
```

Comment: I did finally get it to work without error by downloading an older version of Python (3.11) and using pip3.11 install openai. That seemed to work. I'm new to Python and don't have older versions or Pyenv set up. Using it to experiment with Chat GPT functions only.

Comment: You certainly don't need to go as far back as Python 3.9. 3.11 will work fine. The root of the problem is that aiohttp doesn't build with Python 3.12. aiohttp 3.9.0 will resolve this. It's been in beta for about three weeks. https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/#history

Comment: Absolutely, @mikenerone -- I just mentioned 3.9.18 as that's the one I happened to have lying about and found to work.  Useful info about the upcoming resolution!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, tried many other solutions such as update `pip`, `setuptools`, etc. did not work. Got to this stream, fond a solution.

I would like to thank spogr for the answer (I am new to the site, so cannot comment under that post). Use `pyenv` to revert back to other versions of python worked well for me.

Install `pyenv` if you do not have it yet.

```
brew install pyenv
```

if you do not have `homebrew`, check it out here https://brew.sh/.

once `pyenv` is installed, install past versions of python. I have used 3.11.6 and it worked for me (as of today, it's the second last version, the last version is 3.12.0).

```
pyenv install 3.11.6
```

The rest is the same as in the original answer:

setting global version to 3.11.6

```
pyenv global 3.11.6
```

checking if the version has taken place:

```
python -V
```

now install `openai` (depending on your set-up):

```
pip install openai
```

or

```
pip3 install openai
```

Voilà! Worked!

Comment: This feels like a copy of the comment before yours, also, your command `python -v` is incorrect, it needs to be `-V`.