# error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1 : On installing pandas on MacOS Big Sur M1

Tags: python, xcode, macos, pip, pep

I install pandas using `pip install pandas` or `pip3 install pandas`. I get following infinite like error :

(Note : I run these installations in virtualenv, created using `python3 -m venv myenv`)

```
               /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:328:9: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              npy_intp k;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
      numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c.src:326:14: note: silence by adding parentheses to mark code as explicitly dead
          else if (0 && kth == num - 1) {
                   ^
                   /* DISABLES CODE */ ( )
      22 warnings generated.
      ar: adding 7 object files to build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/libnpysort.a
      warning: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: archive library: build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/libnpysort.a will be fat and ar(1) will not be able to operate on it
      ranlib:@ build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/libnpysort.a
      running build_ext
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
      building 'numpy.core._dummy' extension
      compiling C sources
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64
  
      compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/ruchit/Desktop/V1/Backend/jumbo/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
      clang: numpy/core/src/dummymodule.c
      clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-headerpad,0x1000 -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/dummymodule.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8 -o build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/_dummy.cpython-38-darwin.so
      building 'numpy.core._multiarray_tests' extension
      compiling C sources
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64
  
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common
      compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/ruchit/Desktop/V1/Backend/jumbo/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
      clang: build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/common/mem_overlap.c
      clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-headerpad,0x1000 -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common/mem_overlap.o -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8 -lnpymath -o build/lib.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/_multiarray_tests.cpython-38-darwin.so
      building 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' extension
      compiling C sources
      C compiler: clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64
  
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var/folders
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var/folders/d2
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-install-eu_oftlb
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-install-eu_oftlb/numpy_6d7d3a999a24445dbb5f662254667aec
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-install-eu_oftlb/numpy_6d7d3a999a24445dbb5f662254667aec/numpy
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-install-eu_oftlb/numpy_6d7d3a999a24445dbb5f662254667aec/numpy/_build_utils
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-install-eu_oftlb/numpy_6d7d3a999a24445dbb5f662254667aec/numpy/_build_utils/src
      compile options: '-DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/ruchit/Desktop/V1/Backend/jumbo/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c'
      extra options: '-faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers'
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_scalar.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/buffer.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/common.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/datetime_strings.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/conversion_utils.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/hashdescr.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/nditer_constr.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/refcount.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalarapi.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/temp_elide.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/multiarray/vdot.c
      clang: build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: build/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath/scalarmath.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/common/npy_longdouble.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: numpy/core/src/common/numpyos.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/npymath/halffloat.c
      clang: numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: /private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-install-eu_oftlb/numpy_6d7d3a999a24445dbb5f662254667aec/numpy/_build_utils/src/apple_sgemv_fix.c
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
      error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/ruchit/Desktop/V1/Backend/jumbo/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/ruchit/Desktop/V1/Backend/jumbo/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-install-eu_oftlb/numpy_6d7d3a999a24445dbb5f662254667aec/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-install-eu_oftlb/numpy_6d7d3a999a24445dbb5f662254667aec/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-record-f9lmvg7d/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-build-env-pya4pm20/overlay --compile --install-headers /private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-build-env-pya4pm20/overlay/include/site/python3.8/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/1c/b0bc154996617eae877ff267fcf84e55e6c6808dbade0da206f0419dd483/pandas-1.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=5527c5475d955c0bc9689c56865aaa2a7b13c504d6c44f0aadbf57b565af5ebd (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.7.1). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/ruchit/Desktop/V1/Backend/jumbo/bin/python3 /Users/ruchit/Desktop/V1/Backend/jumbo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/d2/rs5y6mmj7cqftysfzs_x1lg00000gn/T/pip-build-env-pya4pm20/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have updated my pip version. 
I tried to reinstall xcode command line tools again. `xcode-select --install`
I installed `xcode`. 
Tried to update setup tools `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`.
I tried all solutions of this question : [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365790/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-scipy-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installe)

Nothing seems to work, and I'm exhausted. Mac updates are worst. This is happening after I updated my mac last night.

I have also installed cython using `pip install cython`.

Comment: you could try to install pandas from source, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66048187/10600890

Answer (score 3):

Run terminal in rosetta mode then type `pip3 install pandas`

Answer (score 1):

This issue usually occurs for packages that do not have binaries (wheels in the case of python packages) for the M1 Macs.

A solution that I have tried is to build the package from sources from its git repo.

This can be done with a pip install as follows:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git
```

Note the `git+` prefix, this is what informs pip to download it as a package to be built as a wheel otherwise pip will fail to unpack the archive.

You can also add

```
git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git
```

to your requirements.txt

This solution allows pip to build the wheel for your local environment and in the process may introduce conflicts in other packages which may require you to do same for the other failing dependencies as well.

It may be better for other collaborators on the project if you **DO NOT COMMIT** this into your `requirements.txt` unless required.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mac M1 then try the below thing.

```
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The altivec flag in numpy was removed in commit [516bb1a](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/516bb1a1faeb4f0c33f2da9a199ecccabb000469). Now pandas can be installed successfully via

> pip install numpy==1.21.0rc1 pandas

Answer (score 0):

On my MacOS Ventura 13.0.1 with M1 chip, when faced with the error `error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1` during `pip install`, [this answer's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54050463/8631951) of running

> `export CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++'`

prior to `pip install` resolved the error.

Answer (score -2):

Go to https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command%20Line and searach for Command Line Tools (I prefer non Beta version) download it and install from the package.

Comment: It appears he has clang installed - but he's missing a PowerPC chip that supports the -faltivec flag. I'm guessing the problem is that the Makefile detected that the Mac has a non-intel chip and assumed that that means it's a PowerPC chip instead of looking for an M1.